# How to use log_loss scorer in gridsearchcv?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, grid-search

Is it possible to use log_loss metric in gridsearchcv?

I have seen few posts where people mentioned about `neg_log_loss`? Is it same as `log_loss`? If not is it possible to use log_loss directly in gridsearchcv?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As stated in the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html), scoring may take different inputs: string, callable, list/tuple, dict or None. If you use strings, you can find a list of possible entries [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#scoring-parameter).

There, as a string representative for log loss, you find "neg_log_loss", i.e. the negative log loss, which is simply the log loss multiplied by -1. This is an easy way to deal with a maximization problem (which is what GridSearchCV expects, because it requires a score parameter, not a loss parameter), instead of a minimization one (you want the minimum log loss, which is equivalente to the maximum negative log loss).

If instead you want to directly pass a log loss function to the GridSearchCV, you just have to create a scorer from the Scikit-learn [log_loss](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.log_loss.html#sklearn.metrics.log_loss) function by using [make_scorer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.make_scorer.html):

```
from sklearn import svm, datasets
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.metrics import log_loss, make_scorer

iris = datasets.load_iris()
parameters = {'kernel':('linear', 'rbf'), 'C':[1, 10]}
svc = svm.SVC(gamma="scale", probability=True)
LogLoss = make_scorer(log_loss, greater_is_better=False, needs_proba=True)
clf = GridSearchCV(svc, parameters, cv=5, scoring=LogLoss)
clf.fit(iris.data, iris.target)

print(clf.best_score_, clf.best_estimator_)
```

Comment: good call on the `greater_is_better=False` option, make sure to use that